# css table/div formatting of dynamic number of cell elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating an HTML layout for a person's hobbies.  The person may pick anywhere between 1-20  hobbies they like.  I want to display them in rows with 3 columns.  Is there a way to do this with divs so that I don't have to compute when to insert a new row?  For example if I use a table and the user picks 7 hobbies it looks like:

```
<tr><td>hobby 1</td><td>hobby 2</td><td>hobby3</td</tr>
<tr><td>hobby 4</td><td>hobby 5</td><td>hobby6</td</tr>
<tr><td>hobby 7</td><td></td><td></td</tr>
```

and I would have to know when to insert a new row (on the server side when getting the data).  That's a bit of a pain - have I printed another 3 columns? ok, end the row and start a new one.

I'd like something like:

```
<div container>
<div>hobby 1</div>
<div>hobby 2</div>
<div>hobby 3</div>
<div>hobby 4</div>
<div>hobby 5</div>
<div>hobby 6</div>
<div>hobby 7</div>
</div>
```

where the output looks like:

```
hobby1   hobby2   hobby3
hobby4   hobby5   hobby6
hobby7
```

The container will be a fixed size (600px), as well as each cell (200 px)

Comment: have you tried just floating the divs left yet? you'll want to give the divs a consistent width as well so they line up in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a container `.table` of `width: 600px`, just set each child div to `width: 50%` and `float: left` to achieve your desired effect.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div>hobby 1</div>
    <div>hobby 2</div>
    <div>hobby 3</div>
    <div>hobby 4</div>
    <div>hobby 5</div>
    <div>hobby 6</div>
    <div>hobby 7</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
    overflow: hidden; /** Contain floated elements **/
    width: 600px;
}

.table div {
    float: left;
    width: 33%; /** Or, a fixed pixel width of 200px; **/
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/unBsf/1/) [Updated 10/4]

**NOTE:** Updated to display 3 columns, instead of 2. Updated Fiddle example.

Comment: Floating the divs left is the most straightforward solution, but the OP is asking for 3 columns, not 2.

Comment: This works with a change on .table div to width: 200px; for 3 columns instead of width: 50% for 2 columns

Comment: @kinakuta Ha, good point. I have updated the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using CSS columns:

```
<!-- note that I've used 'container' as an id, rather than just free floating
     the string within the tag (which would make it an invalid attribute) -->
<div id="container">
    <div>hobby 1</div>
    <div>hobby 2</div>
    <div>hobby 3</div>
    <div>hobby 4</div>
    <div>hobby 5</div>
    <div>hobby 6</div>
    <div>hobby 7</div>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
#container {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -ms-column-count: 3;
    -o-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9sXMh/1/).

Obviously this solution requires the browser to implement the CSS multi-column layout module, it is possible to use CSS to test for browser-support for a given CSS property-value pair (though this has its problems, and is even less-well supported than CSS columns, however if a browser supports the `@supports ()` syntax then there's a pretty good chance that it also supports the columns:

```
/* defaults, to style if columns are not supported: */
#container {
}
#container div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.2em 0.5em;
}
/* testing for support for the given property-name and the property-value: */
@supports (-moz-column-count: 3) or (-ms-column-count: 3) or (-o-column-count: 3) or (-webkit-clumn-count: 3) or (column-count: 3) {
    /* if the browser supports the property-name and property-value, the following styles are used, if the browser doesn't understand the syntax the rules are discarded */
    #container {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -ms-column-count: 3;
        -o-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
    #container div {
        /* unset the 'if not supported' styling */
        display: block;
        float: none;
        /* aesthetics, just because; adjust to taste */
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9sXMh/2/).

Now, above I said that `@supports` has 'its problems'; to quote Eric Meyer:

> > > A CSS processor is considered to support a declaration (consisting of a property and value) if it accepts that declaration (rather than discarding it as a parse error). If a processor does not implement, with a usable level of support, the value given, then it must not accept the declaration or claim support for it.
>
> So in that first sentence, what we’re told is that “support” means “accepts [a] declaration” and doesn’t drop it on the floor as something it doesn’t recognize.  In other words, if a browser parses a property:value pair, then that qualifies as “support” for said pair.  Note that this sentence says nothing about what happens after parsing.  According to this, a browser could have a completely botched, partial, and generally unusable implementation of the property:value pair, but the act of recognizing means that there’s “support”.

<sub>[Reference: 'Unsupportable Promises', by Eric Meyer, accessed: 2013-10-03, 23:43 (British Summer Time)](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2013/03/19/unsupportable-promises/)</sub>

Despite the above, it *seems* to work (in this case, tested in Chromium 28 on Ubuntu 12.10), but is, apparently, potentially-fragile.

References:

- [Can I Use: Multiple-columns (compatibility information)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn).
- [Can I use: `@supports` (compatibility information)](http://caniuse.com/#search=supports).
- [CSS Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/).
- [CSS `@supports`, from the 'Conditional Rules Module'](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
#hobby{
         display:inline-block;
         width: 197px;
         max-width:197px;
         height:200px;
         max-height:200px;
         margin:0px;
         margin-top:2px;
         overflow:hidden; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3m2NK/4/